# TypeError: must be str, not tuple. Variable as a string in an Array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code I have, I keep getting TypeError: must be str, not tuple

```
variable = ["Variable1", "Variable2"]

def command(self, *arg):
    numparm = len(arg)
    for i in range (0,numparm):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[text()='"+ arg[i] +"']")

command(variable)
```

Answer (score 2):

The *args means unpacked list of parameters, so the tuple should be unpacked: command(*variable) or if you want to pass it as is, you can define command(args) and than call to command(variable).
The self parameter in your code is a typo.

Comment: Perfect, got it working. Thank You!